# MySQL - Converting TEXT datatype (yyyy-mm) to DATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called "month" that I have imported into MySQL:

- Datatype: TEXT
- Display: 2021-01

My goal is to convert this column into some sort of DATE datatype (ie. DATE, DATETIME) so that MySQL will recognize it as yyyy-mm.

I have tried the following method but still received `NULL`

```
--- (1) add dummy date
SELECT CONCAT(month, '-01')
FROM tablename; 

--- (2) convert to DATE datatype 
SELECT CONVERT(month,DATE)
FROM tablename; -- if I just run (1) and (2) i receive NULL

--- (3) Format back to yyyy-mm format
SELECT FORMAT(month,'yyyy-mm') AS month2
FROM tablename; -- If i run from (1) to (3), i receive 2,021
```

So:

1. How do i solve this problem conversion problem in MySQL
2. Is there anyway i could have prevented this before/while importing?

Comment: You know running (1) doesn't change the data, right? And when you then run (2) you're still working with the original `2021-01` value, without the extra `-01` at the end?

Comment: 1) `How do i solve this problem conversion` Once the data is imported into a table, you need to UPDATE the table to make any changes permanent  2)  `...prevented this before/while importing?` Possibly. What tool did you use to import?

Comment: @SOS I used Table Data Import Wizard

Comment: Regarding 2) I'm not sure the Data Import Wizard supports manipulating the data during import. You could use different method like [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) which offers more flexibility when importing, but does require creating the table first . Regarding question 1) I don't get the same result as you.  See this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85f6c58a22d5f933f4d5136e2ee5563b . Could you post a sample of the file you're importing? Just a few lines, and obviously replace any confidential info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a one time migration from your string format to a SQL date or datetime, then you can just do

```sql
UPDATE tablename SET columname = CONCAT(columname, '-01');
```

and then update the column to a `DATE` or a `DATETIME`.

Alternatively if you do not want to update the values you could use the following queries to cast to a DATE or a DATETIME:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(columnname, '-01') AS DATE) FROM tablename
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(columnname, '-01') AS DATETIME) FROM tablename
```